# Splitting WPF interface across multiple Xaml files

Tags: wpf, xaml

I am trying to create a user interface using XAML. However, the file is quickly becoming very large and difficult to work with. What is the best way for splitting it across several files.

I would like to be able to set the content of an element such as a ComboBox to an element that is defined in a different xaml file (but in the same VS project).

thanks

Answer (score 50, accepted):

You can split a large user interface by defining UserControls.

Right-click on the solution tree, choose Add->New Item... then User Control. You can design this in the normal way.

You can then reference your usercontrol in XAML using a namespace declaration. Let's say you want to include your UserControl in a Window. In the following example I've added a UserControl named "Foo" to the namespace "YourCompany.Controls":

```
<Window x:Class="YourCompany.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:Controls="clr-namespace:YourCompany.Controls">

  <Controls:Foo ... />
```

For your specific example, you would make use of your usercontrol in a combobox by defining a DataTemplate that displayed the data within your usercontrol.

Answer (score 30):

You can split up XAML files by using a [ResourceDictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.resourcedictionary.aspx). The ResourceDictionary can be used to merge other files:

```
<Page.Resources>
  <ResourceDictionary>
    <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
      <ResourceDictionary Source="myresourcedictionary.xaml"/>
      <ResourceDictionary Source="myresourcedictionary2.xaml"/>
    </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
  </ResourceDictionary>
</Page.Resources>
```

In the ResourceDictionary, you can also declare Styles that you can use at your elements, such that the main XAML file gets smaller.

Another possibility to get a smaller XAML file is to define your own controls that you then use in your main app.

Comment: Yes, straightforward answer. It also works with <Window.Resources>

Answer (score 3):

You can also create a [Page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.page(v=vs.110).aspx), instead of a `UserControl`. A `Page` can be hosted by the `Window` or by a [Frame](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.frame(v=vs.110).aspx). Search for the pros and cons of a Page vs UserControl. It depends a bit on your requirements with respect to navigation which will suit your needs best.

[Here is an example of using a Page in a Frame.](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/mahesh/using-xaml-frame-in-wpf857/)

Answer (score -1):

Use styles and user controls. Divide your interface on smaller parts and code them in another xaml files.
Example:

`<Window>

  <VeryBigControl>

    <VeryBigControl.Style>

      ... <!--very long style-->

    </VeryBigControl.Style>

    .. <!--content of very big control-->

  </VeryBigControl

</Window>`

divide it into three xaml files:
Window.xaml - this will be Window
VeryBigControl.xaml - this will be UserControl
VeryBigControlStyle.xaml  - this will be resource dictionary
and so on :)