# Splitting a large XAML project among multiple XAML files

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have a large XAML project which will have a main TabControl and each tab "page" will have its own fairly complex set of elements and user interactions.  (This is for a complex industrial control application)

I want the content of each tab to have its own XAML file, partly to avoid having one huge, unmanagable XAML file with everything, and partly so different designers can each work on their own tab.

What's the "right" way to split a XAML project among multiple files?     I've seen static resources and user controls suggested here on Stack Overflow but neither seem to be the "intended" purpose of those features.   The former **appears** to be intended for resources like strings, brushes, colors, styles, templates etc, and the latter **appears** to be intended for custom controls.    What is the "best practice" for splitting a large XAML project among multiple files and designers?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Splitting WPF interface across multiple Xaml files](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/224765/splitting-wpf-interface-across-multiple-xaml-files)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try using DataTemplate's as Resources (and therefore splitting up your resource files) and set their DataType property to a particular piece of UI corresponfding to a particular instance of a Data Object (if this suits your scenario)

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742521.aspx#Styling_DataType

Otherwise use UserControls, as this is now an accepted method for achieveing your requirements.

Comment: There's no question that User Controls _work_ for this scenario but most of the examples and documentation I've seen from MSFT suggest that their intended purpose is to create controls that will be re-used multiple times or put in a control library to be shared among multiple projects, etc.    But since the need to split large XAML projects into multiple files to be less cumbersome or to divide among multiple developers/designers is common in large commercial/industrial projects I (perhaps foolishly) thought MSFT had a feature intended for that, so I don't have to use a spanner for a hammer.

Comment: @user316117 I have the same question as you. Did you find any answers? Why Can't you use frames?

Comment: @user316117 has accepted this answer, and since I share their concerns, I'll follow suit. Having worked with numerous other GUI toolkits and APIs, it seems odd to me, too, but since it does work well and nobody's objecting, I guess it is the 'right' way.

Answer (score 1):

I'd use several UserControls for that because you're combining several controls into one Control and that makes it a lot more efficient because of the overview it creates

Comment: Microsoft desribes the purpose of the UserControl class as a "simple way to create a control".   But I don't need to create any controls -  the stock controls are fine for me.   Each tab will have a particular purpose, for example one will be used to configure a piece of manufacturing equiplent (buttons, checkboxes, etc) another will associate a piece of equipment with a part being manufactured and a parts inventory (radio buttons, some sort of listview bound to a database, etc).     All the controls are very vanilla, but each tab has its own purpose WRT the manufacturing process.

Comment: When you want to create your own control you'll create a CustomControl not an UserControl in my opinion and that's how I work, sorry =)